# How to set data for two section in tableview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

i want add `id: 1,2,3` for section mazda version 2 and 4,5,6 for mazda version 1.5 but i encountered an error in here:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title 
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text
```

> error: Value of type '[(id: Int, title: String, text: String, image:
>   String, color: UIColor)]' has no member 'title'

**Below is my code**

```
import UIKit

struct Headline {

    var id : Int
    var title : String
    var text : String
    var image : String
    var color: UIColor!


}

var headlines = [
    [(id: 1, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 8500000000", image: "mazdared", color: UIColor.red),
     (id: 2, title:  "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 8000000000", image: "mazdablue", color: UIColor.blue),
     (id: 3, title:  "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "mazdablack", color: UIColor.black)] ,

    [(id: 4, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 10000000000", image: "mazdared", color: UIColor.red),
     (id: 5, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9500000000", image: "mazdablue", color: UIColor.blue),
     (id: 6, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "mazdablack", color: UIColor.black)]
]

class CarTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return headlines.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return headlines[section].count
    }

    let headerTitles = ["Mazda Version 2", "Mazda Version 1.5"]
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section < headerTitles.count {
            return headerTitles[section]
        }

        return nil
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        let headline = headlines[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.backgroundColor = headline.color
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: headline.image)


        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with above code?

Comment: i want add id: 1,2,3 for section mazda version 2 and 4,5,6 for mazda version 1,5 but i had 
error in here:
cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text

error: Value of type '[(id: Int, title: String, text: String, image: String, color: UIColor)]' has no member 'title'

Comment: instead of using `cell.textLabel?.text = headline.title` and
`cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline.text`  try `cell.textLabel?.text = headline[indexpath.row].title` and
`cell.detailTextLabel?.text = headline[indexpath.row].text `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made some modifications to your code to make it working.

**Step 1:**

Replace

```
var headlines = [
    [(id: 1, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 8500000000", image: "mazdared", color: UIColor.red),
     (id: 2, title:  "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 8000000000", image: "mazdablue", color: UIColor.blue),
     (id: 3, title:  "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "mazdablack", color: UIColor.black)] ,

    [(id: 4, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 10000000000", image: "mazdared", color: UIColor.red),
     (id: 5, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9500000000", image: "mazdablue", color: UIColor.blue),
     (id: 6, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "mazdablack", color: UIColor.black)]
]
```

With

```
var headlines = [

    [
        Headline(id: 1, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 8500000000", image: "mazdared", color: UIColor.red),
        Headline(id: 2, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 8000000000", image: "mazdablue", color: UIColor.blue),
        Headline(id: 3, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "mazdablack", color: UIColor.black)
    ],
    [
        Headline(id: 4, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 10000000000", image: "mazdared", color: UIColor.red),
        Headline(id: 5, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9500000000", image: "mazdablue", color: UIColor.blue),
        Headline(id: 6, title: "Mazda 3", text: "Price: 9000000000", image: "mazdablack", color: UIColor.black)
    ]
]
```

Here I have initialised struct correctly.

**Step 2:**

In your `cellForRowAt` method Replace

```
let headline = headlines[indexPath.row]
```

with

```
let headline = headlines[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Because with your code when you store `headlines[indexPath.row]` in `headline` object it will become a multidimensional array which won't work here. So I corrected that.

Comment: Sure about that :)

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: If u free time ask skype we can talk more about swift, i begin change from .net to swift, ty so much